# How can a UITableView be populated using NSMutableDictionary keys as cell titles?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I'm sure this is a very simple fix but I cannot seem to find the answer.  I have a populated NSMutableDictionary.  What I would like to do is have my UITableView create a cell for each object in the NSMutableDictionary, using the object's key as the title for the cell.

I have already tried `[mydictionary allkeys]` but I cannot figure out how to translate the indexPath in to an int that could be used in an `objectAtIndex:` query.  Or maybe there is another better way to do it?  The order of these objects is not important as long as they all show up.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[mydictionray allkeys]` is an `NSArray`, so you can just have the indexes of that array correspond to the indexPath row:

```
cell.textLabel.text = [[mydictionary allkeys] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Comment: @Garrett, in CellForRowAtIndexPath method of your UITableView, `cell.textLabel.text=[[yourArray objectAtIndexPath:indexPath.row]];`

Comment: Good call @Hemang; hadn't seen that OP just wanted to use the keys for labels.